# Format Text Editor data to display in Gridview Yii2

Tags: gridview, yii2, yii2-advanced-app

I am using yii2 gridview,
and i have a field named `description` which contains all rich html text with style and format.

Now i know how to display that data in gridview and I can limit the character to  be displayed in grid for that column as well

But i have 2 problems now

1) I used a function in `value` property to `truncate` data so i lost ability to search from description. So how can I `truncate` text and be able to search in that column as well
Here is code I used

```
[
    'format' => 'html',
    'label' => 'Description',
    'value' => function ($dataProvider) {
        $url = $dataProvider->description;
        return BaseStringHelper::truncateWords($url,30,null,true);
    },
],
```

2)This does solve the primary problem but after i use that method i have problem with displaying images in the gridview column. I want to trim the `img` tag if any from `description` data and display data  in gridview and be able to search as well

I hope you guys understand my question. Let me know what can i do

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

1) cant you just make one extra data column in your DB table, then do:

```
$formattedDesc = BaseStringHelper::truncateWords($url,30,null,true);
$model->formattedDescription = $formattedDesc;
```

when you are importing data to your db, to fetch data. 
This you would normally display data from that cell into your gridView.

///

to be able to search again, just add

```
'attribute' => 'your column name',
```

You will probably need to bind your new attribute into your search model

```
  ->andFilterWhere(['like or = /// etc.','columnt that you want to search   in//',
$this->getAttribute('attribute name')]);
```

/* be aware that the search will be made with data from "db column", and that db column data will be displayed ( with your formatted value )

To add custom attributes to your search model:

```
public function attributes() {
    return array_merge(parent::attributes(), ['customAttribute']);
}

public function rules(){
    return [
           [['customAttribute'], 'safe'],
           ];
 }
```

Comment: hey thank you for your replay and that was really useful but i have one more query what happens to `img` tag.. Because in my new db column if the `img` tag is broken from half the string and stored than when i display it, it doesnt display the image just broken string..

Comment: code example would be useful, thought i always use `"format" => "raw"`, to display html in gridView